# How do I delay a for-loop in a recursive function using setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

**Issue:**

I'm trying to make a tool to help me organize a bunch of random photos in a folder along with a bunch of posts in an HTML document. My code works fine and does what it's supposed to do. However there are a lot of photos and I need to slow down a for-loop on my function. It only works for a minute and then the browser keeps crashing. What I'm trying to do is implement a setTimeout function to slow down the loop so I can successfully loop thru all of the data. The main problem is I don't know where to put the setTimeout function or where to call it. I've tried various ways of setting the timeout and I've tried to use an async and await with a sleep function as well. I put HashTags (#'s) around the parts I need help with. The setTimeout at the top of the page and the loop at the bottom. Any help is much appreciated.

Code:

```
<script>

//  **#### DELAY FUNCTION ####**
// **#### BREAKS RECURSION ####**
   
function delay(j) { 

    setTimeout(function() { 
    
    }, 2000 * j);
    
}

function loop(node){
    
    // LOOP THROUGH INDIVIDUAL NODES

    var currentElement = node.childNodes;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < currentElement.length; i++){
    
        // CHECKS FOR RECURSION

        if (!currentElement[i]){
        
            alert("CONTINUED");
            
            continue;
        }

        if (currentElement[i].childNodes.length > 0){
                
            var currElemTag = currentElement[i].tagName;
            var currElemClass = currentElement[i].className;
                
            // PHOTO AND VIDEO, HYPERLINK FILTER
                
            if (currElemTag == 'A') {
                
                var currElemHref = currentElement[i].href;
                
                if (currElemHref.includes('.jpg') == true || currElemHref.includes('.mp4') == true) {

                    
                    // MP4 - JPG HANDLER
                    
                    var outputConsole = document.getElementById('outputConsole');
                    
                    if(currElemHref.includes('.jpg') == true) {
                        var newElement = '<'+currElemTag+' href="'+currElemHref+'">'+'<img src="'+currElemHref+'"></img></A><br>';
                        outputConsole.innerHTML+=newElement+'\r\n';     
                    }
                    
                    if(currElemHref.includes('.mp4') == true) {
                        var newElement = '<'+currElemTag+' href="'+currElemHref+'">'+'<video src="'+currElemHref+'"></video></A><br>';
                        outputConsole.innerHTML+=newElement+'\r\n';     
                    }
        
                }
                
                
            }
                
            // MAIN POST
                
            else if (currElemTag == 'DIV' && currElemClass == "_2pin") {
                
                var currElemStr = currentElement[i].innerHTML;
                

                var mainPost = currElemStr.substring(
                
                    currElemStr.lastIndexOf('<div>') + 5,
                    currElemStr.lastIndexOf('</div>')
                    
                );
                
                var outputConsole = document.getElementById('outputConsole');
                var newElement = '<'+currElemTag+'>'+mainPost+'</DIV><br>';
                outputConsole.innerHTML+=newElement+'\r\n';
                
            }
                
            // SUBPOST OF SPECIFIC PHOTO
                
            else if (currElemTag == 'DIV' && currElemClass == "_3-95") {
                
                var currElemStr = currentElement[i].innerHTML;
                var outputConsole = document.getElementById('outputConsole');
                var newElement = '<'+currElemTag+'>'+currElemStr+'</DIV><br>';
                outputConsole.innerHTML+=newElement+'\r\n'; 
            
            }

            
            // POST DATE
            
            else if (currElemTag == 'DIV' && currElemClass == "_3-94 _2lem") {
                
                var currElemStr = currentElement[i].innerHTML;
                    
                var postDate = currElemStr.substring(
                
                    currElemStr.lastIndexOf('">') + 2,
                    currElemStr.lastIndexOf('</a>')
                    
                );
                    
                var outputConsole = document.getElementById('outputConsole');
                var newElement = '<'+currElemTag+'>'+postDate+'</DIV><br>';
                outputConsole.innerHTML+=newElement+'\r\n\r\n\r\n';
                
                // alert("THE DATE OF THIS POST IS: " + postDate);
                
            }
                
                
            else {
                
                var outputConsole = document.getElementById('outputConsole');
                outputConsole.innerHTML+='ELEMENT DELETED!!!'+'\r\n';
                
                // alert(currElemTag + " Named: " + currElemClass + " WILL BE DELETED!!!");

                
                
            }
            
            // #### FUNCTION LOOPS HERE ####
            // #### START DELAY ####

            delay(i);
            loop(currentElement[i]);
        }       
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code inside the for loop in your setTimeout. You can also pass j as a function parameter.

```
for(var i = 0; i < currentElement.length; i++) {
   setTimeout(function() {
     // Your code
   }, 2000 * j) // Pass j as a function parameter in your loop function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, make your `loop` function `async`, so you can `await` for 2 seconds after every iteration.

You can define the `delay` function to return a `Promise` which will be resolved after some seconds.

```
function delay(millis) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, millis);
    });
}
```

Define your `loop` function as `async` and you are ready to go.

```
async function loop() {
    const currentElement = node.childNodes;
    for (let i = 0; i < currentElement.length; i++){
        // Do your stuff
        
        // Wait for 2 secs
        await delay(2000);
    }
}
```

> I'd recommend you to await the recursive call to `loop` at the end.
>
> ```
> // ...
> await delay(2000);
> await loop(...);
> ```

Hope it helps.